# Error when assigning big number to BigInteger

Tags: c#, biginteger

Trying to assign a large number to a `BigInteger` in C#

```
 BigInteger number= 27419669081321110693270343633073797;
```

but it shows error :

> *Integral constant is too large*

I thought that `BigInteger` is as big as my RAM so how can I move this number to `BigInteger`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can do it with `BigInteger.Parse(String)`. Without knowing a lot about C#, I think the right part of the assignment is the wrong one. The number is too big.

Comment: Yes, the number is too big for the attempted implicit conversion to the `ulong` type (`ulong.MaxValue = 18446744073709551615UL`). `27419669081321110693270343633073797` is a constant declaration, of which `BigInteger` is not a valid type (valid types are `sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, bool, string`, an enum-type, or a reference-type).

Answer (score 0):

I checked on my VS and parsing success.
Try to parse by this method:

```
BigInteger mybigint;
bool checkparse=BigInteger.TryParse("27419669081321110693270343633073797",out  mybigint);
if(checkparse==false)
   //You can't parse this string
else
   //string parsed
```

Answer (score 0):

The `BigInteger` type is an immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose value **in theory** has no upper or lower bounds.

As like [Burkhard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180920/447156) and [Hank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180925/447156) says, you should use [`BigInteger.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268285.aspx) method for this.

```
BigInteger number= BigInteger.Parse("27419669081321110693270343633073797");
```

Also don' forget;

> If you use the `Parse()` method to round-trip the string representation of
>   a `BigInteger` value that was output by the `ToString` method, you should
>   use the `BigInteger.ToString(String)` method with the "R" format
>   specifier to generate the string representation of the `BigInteger`
>   value. Otherwise, the string representation of the `BigInteger`
>   preserves only the **50** most significant digits of the original value,
>   and data may be lost when you use the Parse method to restore the
>   `BigInteger` value.